# Removing duplicate values from dataframe in R when rows are unique

Tags: r, duplicates

This seems like a very simple operation, but I am not able to figure out the problem.

I have the data:

```
> test
          code               city identifier
25051 03017300             Anjira  211710966
25052 03017400             Anjira  211710966
25053 03017400 Maitratrilochanpur  211710981
25054 03017500             Anjira  211710966
25055 03017500 Maitratrilochanpur  211710981
25056 03017600     Khuntiabanapur  211710986
25057 03017700     Khuntiabanapur  211710986
25058 03017900             Anjira  211710966
```

I want to filter for the unique elements in the identifier column. However, when I use the usual command:

```
> test.unique<-test[!duplicated(test$identifier),]

> test.unique
          code               city identifier
25051 03017300             Anjira  211710966
25053 03017400 Maitratrilochanpur  211710981
25056 03017600     Khuntiabanapur  211710986
```

I do not want the 211710966 entry to be there, but somehow I cannot get rid of it.

When I use unique instead, I get a dataframe of NA, even when I have a unique value:

```
          code               city identifier
25051 03017300             Anjira  211710966
25052 03017400             Anjira  211710966
25053 03017400 Maitratrilochanpur  211710981
25054 03017500             Anjira  211710966
25055 03017500 Maitratrilochanpur  211710981
25056 03017600     Khuntiabanapur  211710986
25057 03017700     Khuntiabanapur  211710986
25058 03017900             Anjira  211710966
9     03018100               Test    1000000


> test.unique<-test[unique(test$identifier),]
> test.unique
     code city identifier
NA   <NA> <NA>       <NA>
NA.1 <NA> <NA>       <NA>
NA.2 <NA> <NA>       <NA>
NA.3 <NA> <NA>       <NA>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong, as I have done this in the past and it has worked (or maybe I have been doing it wrong the whole time).

Thank you.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I wanted to filter just by the identifier column. Thanks for your answer, I think it will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(code, city, identifier) %>% filter(n()<2)
```

With `data.table`, you would do :

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, n:=.N, by = c("code", "city", "identifier")][n<2]
```

NB: `unique` should be favored if you select rows using **all** your columns (cf. @akrun answer)

Comment: Thanks. The dplyr did what after grouping by identifier only.

Answer (score 2):

If it is for all the columns

```
test[!duplicated(test),]
```

Or with `unique`

```
unique(test)
```

---

I we want to get the `unique` by 'identifier' use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
     distinct(identifier, .keep_all = TRUE)
```